# {{node.hostname}} usage in docker-compose.yml in Docker swarm mode

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Hi I am looking at above example and trying to run docker swarm stack but getting below error. not sure what I am missing here.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    hostname: '{{.Node.Hostname}}'
version: '3.3'
```

docker stack deploy test -c docker-compose.yml

> but getting below output/error : Error response from daemon: rpc
>   error: code = InvalidArgument desc = expanding hostname failed:
>   template: expansion:1:7: executing "expansion" at <.Node.Hostname>:
>   can't evaluate field Hostname in type struct { ID string }

Here is my docker-info output:

docker info Containers:

12 Running: 0 Paused: 0 Stopped: 
12 Images: 41 
**Server Version: 18.03.1-ce** 
Storage Driver: devicemapper 
Pool Name: docker-253:1-2490377-pool Pool 
Blocksize: 65.54kB Base 
Device Size: 10.74GB Backing Filesystem:

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try with double quotes ?
And put the version on top of the file

Comment: I am running to the same issue, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your setup with both `version: '3.3'` and `version: '3.4'` of compose.

According to https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#create-services-using-templates hostname is one of the fields you can use template strings on so this should work fine.

After creating the stack I verified the hostname with

```
$ docker inspect test_nginx | grep name
"com.docker.stack.namespace": "test"
"com.docker.stack.namespace": "test"
"Hostname": "{{.Node.Hostname}}",
```

So I think either this has been fixed in a more recent version of docker or something is odd with your host setup.